# XQuery 3 merging two node sequences and de-duplicating

Tags: xquery, exist-db

In XQuery 3.1 (under eXistDB 4.4) I have two functions which return two sets of nodes that describe family relations of a person. The results of the two functions can overlap.

A first function `person:person-relationship-as-object("#Guilhem_Faure_SML-AU")` returns:

```
<person relation="Peire_Faure_SML-AU">
  <span class="en">Sibling(s)</span>
  <span class="fr">Frère(s)/sœur(s)</span>
</person>

<person relation="Arnald_Faure_SML-AU">
  <span class="en">Sibling(s)</span>
  <span class="fr">Frère(s)/sœur(s)</span>
</person>

<person relation="Esteve_Faure_SML-AU">
  <span class="en">Sibling(s)</span>
  <span class="fr">Frère(s)/sœur(s)</span>
</person>

<person relation="Martin_de_Verazilh_SML-AU">
  <span class="en">Aunt(s)/Uncle(s)</span>
  <span class="fr">Tante(s)/Oncle(s)</span>
</person>

<person relation="Raimund_de_Verazilh_SML-AU">
  <span class="en">Aunt(s)/Uncle(s)</span>
  <span class="fr">Tante(s)/Oncle(s)</span>
</person>
```

A second function `person:person-relationship-as-subject("#Guilhem_Faure_SML-AU")`  returns

```
<person relation="Arnald_Faure_SML-AU">
  <span class="en">Sibling(s)</span>
  <span class="fr">Frère(s)/sœur(s)</span>
</person>

<person relation="Peire_Faure_SML-AU">
  <span class="en">Sibling(s)</span>
  <span class="fr">Frère(s)/sœur(s)</span>
</person>

<person relation="Esteve_Faure_SML-AU">
  <span class="en">Sibling(s)</span>
  <span class="fr">Frère(s)/sœur(s)</span>
</person>

<person relation="Bernarda_Guilhem_Faure_SML-AU">
  <span class="en">Spouse(s)</span>
  <span class="fr">Époux/épouse(s)</span>
</person>
```

Now I want to merge the two sets of nodes into one, and return each distinct node only once.

I attempted a rough SQL-like structure, but failed:

```
let $x := person:person-relationship-as-object("#Guilhem_Faure_SML-AU") 
          | person:person-relationship-as-subject("#Guilhem_Faure_SML-AU")

for $y in $x

order by $y/@relation ascending

group by $y/@relation, $y/span[@class="en"], $y/span[@class="fr"]

return $y
```

I don't think I really understand why the `group by` doesn't work here. Moreover, if `group by` doesn't do the job, how else can I approach what (I think?) should be a simple exercise in grouping/distinct results?

Comment: [return functx:distinct-deep($x)](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_distinct-deep.html)  does the job, without grouping...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With XQuery and `group by`, the variable `$y` in your `return` clause is bound to the whole group you have created so to eliminate duplicates you need to use `return $y[1]`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by which says

> In the post-grouping tuple generated for a given group, each
>   non-grouping variable is bound to a sequence containing the
>   concatenated values of that variable in all the pre-grouping tuples
>   that were assigned to that group.

and then

> This behavior may be surprising to SQL programmers, since SQL reduces
>   the equivalent of a non-grouping variable to one representative value.